# Are column store databases relevant in the age of SSD storage?

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, hbase

Do column store databases such as Cassandra or Hbase (or Postgres with column store) maintain their advantages when using SSDs as storage? One of the main benefits of the column stores, is that range queries are very fast, because in theory they require only one seek, and then are read contiguously from the storage medium. Even for spinning disks this is very fast because you're reading at full speed along the fastest dimension of the medium. But is there a concept of a "contiguous read" in an SSD? IE is reading along one dimension faster than others? If not, are the column stores still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

If used correctly, columnar storage will use less I/O than fetching the whole rows. Less I/O always means better performance, no matter how fast your I/O subsystem is.